# Void function is causing compiler error "variable or field ‘funcName’ declared void"

Tags: c++

I have declared a helper function to a method of a class I declared in a header file, and for some reason when I compile the source code file I get an error telling me that I declared a variable or field as void.  I am not sure how to interpret this since my goal was for the function to be declared void.

The compiler errors are as follows:

```
k-d.cpp:10: error: variable or field ‘insert_Helper’ declared void
k-d.cpp:10: error: ‘node’ was not declared in this scope
k-d.cpp:10: error: ‘root’ was not declared in this scope
k-d.cpp:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
k-d.cpp:10: error: ‘o’ was not declared in this scope
k-d.cpp:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
```

The equivalent of line 10 in the code below is line 5.

The Source Code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "k-d.h" //Defines the node and spot structs
using namespace std;

void insert_Helper(node *root, spot *o, int disc) {
    (...Some code here...)
}

void kdTree::insert(spot *o) {  //kdTree is a class outlined in k-d.h
    insert_Helper(root, o, 0); //root is defined in k-d.h
}
```

If anybody can spot anything that would cause the compiler to not see this as a function it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

P.S. I didn't tag this as a kdtree post because I'm pretty sure the solution does not depend on that aspect of the code.

Update:

Here is k-d.h:

```
#ifndef K_D_H
#define K_D_H 

// Get a definition for NULL
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "p2.h"
#include "dlist.h"

class kdTree {
    // OVERVIEW: contains a k-d tree of Objects

 public:

    // Operational methods

    bool isEmpty();
    // EFFECTS: returns true if tree is empy, false otherwise

    void insert(spot *o);
    // MODIFIES this
    // EFFECTS inserts o in the tree

    Dlist<spot> rangeFind(float xMax, float yMax);

    spot nearNeighbor(float X, float Y, string category);

    // Maintenance methods
    kdTree();                                   // ctor
    ~kdTree();                                  // dtor

 private:
    // A private type
    struct node {
        node *left;
        node *right;
        spot *o;
    };

    node   *root; // The pointer to the 1st node (NULL if none)
};

#endif
```

And p2.h:

```
#ifndef P2_H
#define P2_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum  {
    xCoor = 0,
    yCoor = 1
};

struct spot {
    float key[2];
    string name, category;
};

#endif
```

Comment: You need to post a sufficient code sample that demonstrates the issue. Try to isolate it down to the absolute bare minimum case where the error occurs - 9 times out of 10, that will solve the problem for you anyway, and if it hasn't you can post it and someone should spot the error very quickly.

Comment: Please provide an example that we can use to reproduce the error, as described [here](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Are you certain than both `node` and `spot` are declared by the time `insert_Helper` function is defined? You could include the code for that function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to qualify `kdTree::node` because it's declared as an inner struct. Secondly, you have to make `insert_Helper` a member of your class because `node` is private.

Extra tip: remove the `using` directives from the `.h` files, and rather qualify all your usage of `string`, etc. Consider including that header in a lot of `cpp` files.

Comment: If he makes it a member of the class, then he won't need to qualify it.

Comment: I think I'll actually do that instead of making the node public.  I was trying to keep that as a "hidden" part of the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the "using", I should get out of that habit of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

`node` is a nested type within `kdTree`, in your function definition you have to name it as `kdTree::node`. However, since `node` is private, you will have to do something about that as well.

Comment: I was trying to keep that one inside the class, but I think its going to have to be a public member.  Thanks for the advice, I hate when I run into stupid errors like this :-

Comment: meant to put a smiley there but hit the enter key instead of the shift lol

Comment: @smitty: You don't necessarily have to make it public, it looks like your class could use a friend.

Comment: @smitty you don't need to make node a public member. It's actually better if it's private, you only need access to it from your class. Rather, make the helper function a member of your class.

Comment: As I said in a comment to Luchian's answer I think I am going to go that route